# How to convert a double to long without casting?

Tags: java, type-conversion

What is the best way to convert a double to a long without casting?

For example:

```
double d = 394.000;
long l = (new Double(d)).longValue();
System.out.println("double=" + d + ", long=" + l);
```

Comment: just make sure you do not operate with doubles more than 2 ^ 54 or numbers will not fit into the [fraction](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.3), so for example expressions like `myLong == (long)(myDouble + 1)` where `myLong` equals `myDouble` will evaluate to `true`

Comment: This method ( `Double.longValue();` ) is still useful if you have double values from things like an arraylist like this `ArrayList<Double>` since you'll get a can't cast error. I'm just saying this for anyone that came here and had a slightly different problem.

Answer (score 276):

Assuming you're happy with truncating towards zero, just cast:

```
double d = 1234.56;
long x = (long) d; // x = 1234
```

This will be faster than going via the wrapper classes - and more importantly, it's more readable. Now, if you need rounding other than "always towards zero" you'll need slightly more complicated code.

Comment: Great answer - the towards zero part would have been wrong for my app, so applause for highlighting this in your answer, and reminding my hungover brain to use Math.round() here instead of just casting !

Answer (score 145):

... And here is the rounding way which doesn't truncate. Hurried to look it up in the Java API Manual:

```
double d = 1234.56;
long x = Math.round(d); //1235
```

Comment: It doesn't give the same result as a cast. So it depends on what rich wants to do.

Comment: yeah. it was thought as an addition to what Jon said :)

Comment: I like this since it also works with Double and Long objects rather than primitive types.

Answer (score 70):

The preferred approach should be:

```
Double.valueOf(d).longValue()
```

From the [Double (Java Platform SE 7) documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(double):

```
Double.valueOf(d)
```

> Returns a `Double` instance representing the specified `double` value.
>   If a new `Double` instance is not required, this method should
>   generally be used in preference to the constructor `Double(double)`,
>   as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time
>   performance by caching frequently requested values.

Comment: This is more convenient than the accepted answer

Answer (score 37):

`(new Double(d)).longValue()` internally just does a cast, so there's no reason to create a Double object.

Answer (score 14):

Guava Math library has a method specially designed for converting a double to a long:

```
long DoubleMath.roundToLong(double x, RoundingMode mode)
```

You can use `java.math.RoundingMode` to specify the rounding behavior.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a strong suspicion that the DOUBLE is actually a LONG, and you want to

1) get a handle on its EXACT value as a LONG

2) throw an error when its not a LONG

you can try something like this:

```
public class NumberUtils {

    /**
    * Convert a {@link Double} to a {@link Long}.
    * Method is for {@link Double}s that are actually {@link Long}s and we just
    * want to get a handle on it as one.
    */
    public static long getDoubleAsLong(double specifiedNumber) {
        Assert.isTrue(NumberUtils.isWhole(specifiedNumber));
        Assert.isTrue(specifiedNumber <= Long.MAX_VALUE && specifiedNumber >= Long.MIN_VALUE);
        // we already know its whole and in the Long range
        return Double.valueOf(specifiedNumber).longValue();
    }

    public static boolean isWhole(double specifiedNumber) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963895/how-to-check-if-a-double-value-has-no-decimal-part
        return (specifiedNumber % 1 == 0);
    }
}
```

Long is a subset of Double, so you might get some strange results if you unknowingly try to convert a Double that is outside of Long's range:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    // Confirm that LONG is a subset of DOUBLE, so numbers outside of the range can be problematic
    Assert.isTrue(Long.MAX_VALUE < Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Assert.isTrue(Long.MIN_VALUE > -Double.MAX_VALUE); // Not Double.MIN_VALUE => read the Javadocs, Double.MIN_VALUE is the smallest POSITIVE double, not the bottom of the range of values that Double can possible be

    // Double.longValue() failure due to being out of range => results are the same even though I minus ten
    System.out.println("Double.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE).longValue(): " + Double.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE).longValue());
    System.out.println("Double.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE - 10).longValue(): " + Double.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE - 10).longValue());

    // casting failure due to being out of range => results are the same even though I minus ten
    System.out.println("(long) Double.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE): " + (long) Double.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE).doubleValue());
    System.out.println("(long) Double.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE - 10).longValue(): " + (long) Double.valueOf(Double.MAX_VALUE - 10).doubleValue());
}
```

Comment: `Long is a subset of Double` is not accurate. The number of significant digits for Long is greater that Double, thus some information held by Long can be lost when converted to Double. Example = https://tio.run/##dY3BCoJAEIbP@hSDECjU0j06eOimJymCiNhcldVxV9xRiPDZt5G6dprh/2a@v5Wz3NmhMq3qvB@mJ@oSSpTOQS61gXcY/EJHknjMVivoGcUFjdo0tzvIsXHJehmgNQ0gwhEy3kSeXh@XNDufDsyUZU8FSjFFXJPi5ajqhZ1IDKwiNDFi8od820Rtx15SHG3Evo62bEvWhyVcvP8A

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo `double` can store a wider range of numerical information than `long`. Take a look at the sections about `long` and `double` on this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp).

Answer (score 5):

Simply by the following:

```
double d = 394.000;
long l = d * 1L;
```

Answer (score 1):

better to use `new BigDecimal(s).longValue()`

this is my test, s is raw string of a long value sometimes end with `.0`

cast double to long(`(long) DoubleValue`) or `Double.longValue()` sometimes will losing 1(why?).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8754567/6494418

```java
1651465142958862337, s
1.65146514295886234E18, Double.parseDouble(s)
1.65146514295886234E18, Double.valueOf(s)
1651465142958862340, String.format("%.0f", Double.parseDouble(s)).split("\\.")[0]
1651465142958862336, (long) Double.parseDouble(s)
1651465142958862336, Double.valueOf(s).longValue()
1651465142958862336, Math.round(Double.parseDouble(s))
1651465142958862337, new BigDecimal(s).longValue()  // correct


1.651465142958862337E18, s
1.65146514295886234E18, Double.parseDouble(s)
1.65146514295886234E18, Double.valueOf(s)
1651465142958862340, String.format("%.0f", Double.parseDouble(s)).split("\\.")[0]
1651465142958862336, (long) Double.parseDouble(s)
1651465142958862336, Double.valueOf(s).longValue()
1651465142958862336, Math.round(Double.parseDouble(s))
1651465142958862337, new BigDecimal(s).longValue()  // correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, casting is more efficient than creating a Double object.