# Convert Double to String value preserving every digit

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

How do I convert a double value with 10 digits for e.g 9.01236789E9 into a string 9012367890 without terminating any of its digits ?

I tried 9.01236789E9 * Math.pow(10,9) but the result is still double "9.01236789E18"

Comment: There might be people who take offense to being called geeks.

Comment: You probably want to cast to a long.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321549/double-to-long-conversion for an explaination

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While 10 digits should be preservable with no problems, if you're interested in the actual digits used, you should probably be using `BigDecimal` instead.

If you *really* want to format a `double` without using scientific notation, you should be able to just use `NumberFormat` to do that or (as of Java 6) the simple string formatting APIs:

```
import java.text.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double value = 9.01236789E9;
        String text = String.format("%.0f", value);
        System.out.println(text); // 9012367890

        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        format.setGroupingUsed(false);
        System.out.println(format.format(value)); // 9012367890
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
    double d = 9.01236789E9;    
    System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(d).toPlainString());
```

Comment: Thanks Prince. This is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `String.format("%20.0f",  9.01236789E9)`

Note though it's never an exact value, so "preserving every digit" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

```
String doubleString = Double.toString(inValue)
```

inValue -----> Described by you.to what position you want to Change double to a string.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can also do

```
double value = 9.01236789E9;
System.out.println((long) value); // prints 9012367890
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I realised it later that simply .longValue() could also do.

Comment: `.longValue()` works if you create a `Double` first. Using a cast doesn't require an object.