# Coding up to Factorial 23 in Java

Tags: java, factorial

I need to write up factorial up to 23! I can do factorial up to 20! but after that I am lost because the number gets too big. **I cannot use BigInteger.**

I have to store the 0s from the rightmost digit so example outputs:

10! = 3628800 --> fac=36288, num10 = 2

23! = 2585..976640000 --> fac= 2585..97664, num10 = 4

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial10{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long fac;       // long: factorial is very large
        long pre_fac;       // to check overflow
        int i, n;
        int num10;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("n? ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        // Start from fac = 0! = 1
        for(i= 1, fac= 1L; i<n; i++){
            pre_fac = fac;
            fac *= i;

            // check if overflowed
            if(pre_fac != fac /i){
                System.out.println("Overflowed at " + i + "! = " + fac);
                fac = pre_fac;      // roll back to the previous, unoverflowed
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println((i-1) + "! = " + fac + "(fac = , num10 = )");
    }
}
```
````

Comment: any particular reason you tag this as c or c++ ?

Comment: @Stultuske If somebody knows how to do it in C or C++ I can usually translate it to Java

Comment: `23!` won't fit in 64 bits. Try using `BigInteger` maybe.

Comment: Use a dedicated class that is made for operations on big numbers. Like BigInteger.

Comment: @Michael The whole point is that I can fit it into the 64 bits, that's why I have to store the 0s somewhere

Comment: @Amongalen Yeah I can't use the BigInteger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StackOverflowError computing factorial of a BigInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992437/stackoverflowerror-computing-factorial-of-a-biginteger)

Comment: @HakanDilek I can't use BigInteger but thank you :)

Comment: So the assignment is basically, you need to "reinvent" BigInteger ...

Comment: Then you have to implement your own version of BigInteger based on an array or something like that.

Comment: @JustTryingToGraduate In that case I'm not sure I see what the issue is. If I write a simple C++ example based on your code I get the output you're expecting. Why did you comment out that while-loop?

Comment: Just a mention.. that if I input '5' it gives me a factorial 4! . Is that delibrate ? Else, you change you condiyion at if block to =>

Comment: @AdityaRewari Yes it's done like that on purpose

Comment: Btw. I've run just fine till 26!. Just then it overflows so don't know what your issue is with 23!

Comment: @Amongalen Hmm interesting. I can't go pass 20! without it overflowing

Comment: My bad, I've only looked when it gets negative which obviously wasn't a correct approuch. But till 23! all numbers are fine. I've basicly removed the if statement and uncommented the part with division you removed a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Amongalen Ahhh I did that too and it does go up to 23! now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most miss a crucial part of your question:

> I have to store the 0s from the rightmost digit

10 has the factors 2 and 5, so you only need to store how often each number between 1 and 23 can be divided by 2 and 5.

For example, with 10:

```
i    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10    SUM
div2 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0  1      8
div5 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  1      2
```

As we can see, the minimum of both sums is `2`, so `10!` should end with `00`.
Indeed, `10!` is `3628800`.
The math behind this is `10! = x * 2^8 * 5^2`, for some x that can't be divided by 2 or 5.

An other observation is that the number of 5s increases much slower, so we can skip counting the 2s.

With this knowledge, we can calculate the number of ending 0s by checking how often each number divides 5:

```
private static int numZerosInFactorial(int n) {
    int divBy5 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         for (int j = i; (j % 5) == 0; j /= 5) {
             divBy5++;
         }
    }
    return divBy5;    
}
```

(There are are a few small improvements you can do to the above method)

The other question now is: Do you really need the value of `n!`?
And if yes, with what precision? Is it fine to calculate `n!` with `double` now?

---

Thanks to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382594/coding-up-to-factorial-23-in-java/61384204?noredirect=1#comment108591599_61384204) from [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524450/michael), I noticed that we can in fact calculate the factorial without the zeros and then use string concatenation to display the result.

When calculating the factorial without zeroes, we have to basically do the opposite of what we did in `numZerosInFactorial`, so instead of multiplying with a multiple of 5, we divide by 2:

```
private static long factorialWithoutZeroes(int n) {
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        long div = 1;
        int j;
        for (j = i; (j % 5) == 0; j /= 5) {
            div *= 2;
        }
        result = result / div * j;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The final result would be:

```
// We have already read n from stdin
long fac = factorialWithoutZeroes(n);
int num10 = numZerosInFactorial(n);
System.out.println(n + "! = " + (fac + "0".repeat(num10)) + " (fac = " + fac + " , num10 = " + num10 + ")");
```

Indeed, this approach works up to `n == 23`. And the output format is a good hint that this is the expected approach.

Comment: First of all thank you for noticing that part of the question! What you did above I had something similar but I left out in this question because it wasn't working properly, now it works. My only problem now is that I need to print out the original factorial value (so with the 0s attached to it) so, 23! = 25852016738884976640000.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was asking if you can now do this calculation with `double`, as you don't need the precision to calculate the number of 0s..

Comment: I thought I can just multiply the fac (2585201673888497664) by 10000 and it'll give me 25852016738884976640000 but it doesn't. Is it possible to use double and get the value I need?

Comment: Why can't you just do `for (int i = 0; i < zeroes; ++i) print('0');` ?

Comment: Thanks @Michael, will include this in my answer.

Comment: @JustTryingToGraduate Here. [ideone](https://ideone.com/hRlTlX) to test it online. (includes a method which uses BigInteger to compare the results).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use double instead of long. As documentation in Double.Max - it can hold up to 1.7976931348623157e+308

Comment: I did but I need the 0s at the end so I can't use double

Comment: The fact that it can hold a number up to that value doesn't mean it will be precise. That's the problem with floating point types. Maybe in case of 23! it won't be that noticable but the error is there. I've done a small test and if I'm correct the difference between double and BigDecimal is 3360000 when calculating 23!.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement your own kind of big integer:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] factorial = factorial(n);
    for (int i = factorial.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      System.out.print(factorial[i]);
    }
  }

  static int[] factorial(int n) {
    int[] factorial = { 1 };
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      factorial = multiply(factorial, i);
    }
    return factorial;
  }

  static int[] multiply(int[] multiplicand, int multiplicator) {
    int carry = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < multiplicand.length; j++) {
      multiplicand[j] = multiplicand[j] * multiplicator + carry;
      carry = multiplicand[j] / 10;
      multiplicand[j] %= 10;
    }
    while (carry > 0) {
      multiplicand= Arrays.copyOf(multiplicand, multiplicand.length + 1);
      multiplicand[multiplicand.length - 1] = carry % 10;
      carry /= 10;
    }
    return multiplicand;
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZI9b4MwEIb3/Ip3iUSaQKAdCZE6dqg6ZEQZXEKIqTHImFQoym@n5tsgOsDZ9/ncnWNyJ2Z8@akqmmSpkIiVwiokZda7EKTM3VXASJ7jk1COxwrIim9GA@SSSCXuKb0gUTbjJAXlkX8GEVG@aVwByiU4PHxwGUahsDIi8lBdjNrJt88bt3dTgVcSyFRQwlTAcDZ453NNBYw6H9XNFgt5JG8w4bjKcvRgK2maPQBwKnMZJlZaSCtThNIYYn3a13@u6k/9uq5mPE1ZrvU0g33AwXOBskE6eOBKbrcjkh6bFEzSjJUj1g5UwwJEKAvBxyB3EXbIM7nSgPDLrlnDqFFp9P0ERIgS9eCmHcSNTonDJFs3cWXQW9I9/Pg8NjZoXqYE2LaF3S5BTzEP28Ox3X@KrL3B2I7q90ZZCKPNdYS9zOehfdpWkGbl19WYzmqhV8XqbBYhlpzVU6z7byHWGn6r2c@hu/3qqdoVP6uqen37Aw)

Answer (score -1):

If you can't use `BigInteger`, then you could try implementing your own big number library:

[How to handle very large numbers in Java without using java.math.BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/how-to-handle-very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger/5318896#5318896)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the class BigDecimal of **`java.lang.math`**

But that can take all your memory.

[Is there any replacement of long double in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754410/is-there-any-replacement-of-long-double-in-java)

Comment: _"I cannot use BigInteger."_ - OP

Comment: OP commented that he can't use BigInteger/Decimal.