# How do i remove .0 from the result if the resultant number is a full number in a calculator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an android calculator in android studio. But, in my calculator when the result is a full number, the number appears with decimal 0. 
For example, if i add 9 and 11 the result is appearing as 20.0

So, how do i remove .0 from the result for a full number(ex:- 10,24).

This is my MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.faendir.rhino_android.RhinoAndroidHelper;

import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ast.Scope;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button btn0,btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9,btnPercent,btnPlus,btnMinus,btnMultiply,btnDivision,btnEqual,btnClear,btnDot,btnBracket,btnBackspace;
    TextView tvInput,tvOutput;
    String process;
    boolean checkBracket = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn0 = findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8 = findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9 = findViewById(R.id.btn9);

        btnPlus = findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        btnMinus = findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        btnDivision = findViewById(R.id.btnDivision);
        btnMultiply = findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply);

        btnEqual = findViewById(R.id.btnEqual);

        btnClear = findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnDot = findViewById(R.id.btnDot);
        btnPercent = findViewById(R.id.btnPercent);
        btnBracket = findViewById(R.id.btnBracket);
        btnBackspace = findViewById(R.id.btnBackspace);



        tvInput = findViewById(R.id.tvInput);
        tvOutput = findViewById(R.id.tvOutput);

        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvInput.setText("");
                tvOutput.setText("");
            }
        });


        btn0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "0");
            }
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "1");
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "2");
            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "3");
            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "4");
            }
        });

        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "5");
            }
        });

        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "6");
            }
        });

        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "6");
            }
        });

        btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "7");
            }
        });

        btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "8");
            }
        });

        btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "9");
            }
        });

        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "+");
            }
        });


        btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "-");
            }
        });

        btnMultiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "×");
            }
        });

        btnDivision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "÷");
            }
        });

        btnDot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + ".");
            }
        });

        btnPercent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                tvInput.setText(process + "%");
            }
        });

        btnBracket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (checkBracket){
                    process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                    tvInput.setText(process + ")");
                    checkBracket = false;
                }else{
                    process = tvInput.getText().toString();
                    tvInput.setText(process + "(");
                    checkBracket = true;
                }

            }
        });

        btnBackspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str=tvInput.getText().toString();
                if (str.length() >=1 ) {
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
                    tvInput.setText(str);
                } else if (str.length() <=1 ) {
                    tvInput.setText("0");
                }
            }
        });

        btnEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = tvInput.getText().toString();

                process = process.replaceAll("×","*");
                process = process.replaceAll("%","/100");
                process = process.replaceAll("÷","/");

                Context rhino = Context.enter();

                rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);

                String finalResult = "";

                try {
                    Scriptable scriptable = rhino.initStandardObjects();
                    finalResult = rhino.evaluateString(scriptable,process,"javascript",1,null).toString();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    finalResult="0";
                }

                tvOutput.setText(finalResult);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15963957/13528037

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Answer (score 0):

There could be other solutions to your problem. I am proposing this one.
Put an if() condition to check if the answer is whole number or not.

```
if(result == (int)result){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0")
    return df.format(result);
}
return result;
```

Comment: Where do I insert the above code in MainActivity.java

Comment: you can get help from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0    and use in your final result of btnEqual's clicklistener.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is a whole number or not by simply doing this:

```
if (finalResult % 1 == 0){

  //then the finalResult is a whole number.

}
```