# Convert a Double to long without losing the exact value

Tags: java

I have a `Double` object which loses the exact value when being converted to a `long` value.

```
Double d = 1.14*100
    
System.out.println(d.longValue());
```

The above statement would print: `113`.

I want `114` to be printed.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not exact. Do you want to round first?

Comment: Be aware that what you think is the Double value 114 may actually be 113.99999999... internally, and your code ends up just truncating the decimal portion. As Tim S suggested, you need to incorporate rounding.

Comment: If you want to prevent your code from loosing precision you probably should use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321549/double-to-long-conversion

Comment: Agreed with @Pshemo -- unless there's some good compelling reason to use `Double`, you'd be much better off with `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need the exact 114 value you ned to use `Math.round`:

```
double d = 1.14*100;
System.out.println(Math.round(d));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for an integer / long value representation with the value you are expecting, you can use this:

```
Math.round(1.14 * 100)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Long.parseLong( String.format( "%.0f",doublevalue ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a `double` is *not* exact. Next, when *casting* a `double`/`float` to a `long`/`int`, the decimal part is dropped (not rounded).

To get the *nearest* value, you'll need to *round* it:

```
System.out.println(Math.round(d));
```