# Casting double (primitive) to Long ( Wrapper )

Tags: java, casting

I have to cast primitive double to Long ( Wrapper) at multiple locations in my code. These are 2 ways I could work with -

```
linkcatch.setCode(Long.valueOf((long) relatedCd.getDouble(value)));
```

( casting primitive double to primitive long and then Wrapper Long)

```
linkcatch.setCode(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(relatedCd.getDouble(value))));
```

( casting double to String to Wrapper Long )

Is there any way to cast from native double to Wrapper long without doing the intermediate casting.

I am concerned because there are numerous locations where i need to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You use native but I think you mean primitive?  That's not what native means.

Comment: Just do the primitive conversion. What do you think the wrapper class is wrapping, exactly? A primitive long. You can't get away from doing that conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast and java autoboxing will convert to the Long object type for you. No need to make special libraries or extra methods (stay lean!)

```
linkcatch.setCode((long)relatedCd.getDouble(value));
```

Notes:

- You might want to round instead of just casting.  ([double to long conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321549/double-to-long-conversion))
- I see you have a 'realtedCd' object which means you might be dealing with money or arithmetic operations. If so, I'd advise using BigDecimal instead of doubles for precision [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the casting in every java statement, you can create static method which takes a double value as argument, do the casting and return a Long object. In this way, it's easy to maintain and the reusabilty of the code without redundancy

Answer (score 1):

Found a shorter way to make it. You can use Math.Round to get the long native value. After that you can simply cast it to long

```
double a = -5.42
Long = (Long)Math.round(a);
```

However another approach would be too do something like making another class to do the work for you.

```
public class Util{

    public static Long getLong(double a){
         return (Long)Math.round(a);
    }
}
```

This way your code would look something like this

```
linkcatch.setCode(Util.getLong(value));
```

instead of

```
linkcatch.setCode(Long.valueOf((long) relatedCd.getDouble(value)));
```

or

```
linkcatch.setCode(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(relatedCd.getDouble(value))));
```

Hope it helps your to make your code cleaner and easier to manage. Also if you want all the Long values to Round up or down, you have a single place to edit(The Util class), instead of 100 different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Long l = new Double(relatedCd.getDouble(value)).longValue();
```

Java autoboxing will help you do other things.