# How to get long value in lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda

I am new here, and I hope that you will help me.
I have a javascript function and there i call a function like this:

```
var criticalDateStart = new Date(1525683802394);
var criticalDateEnd = new Date(1525770202394);

var users = enumerateUsers({
    userId : userId,
    criticalDateStart : criticalDateStart.getTime(),
    criticalDateEnd : criticalDateEnd.getTime(),
});
```

Furthemore, I have a lambda function on the server, that looks like this:

```
Function<Object, Object> enumeratePatients = (arg) -> {

        if (arg instanceof ScriptObjectMirror) {
            ScriptObjectMirror _arg = (ScriptObjectMirror) arg;
            Integer userId = (Integer) _arg.get("userId");
            Long criticalDateStart = (Long)_arg.get("criticalDateStart");   
            Long criticalDateEnd = (Long)_arg.get("criticalDateEnd");

            ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
            ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = client.target(Url);
            Rest rest = rtarget.proxy(Rest.class);
                return rest.enumerateUsers(
                         new EnumerateUserParameter(
                           userId, 
                           criticalDateStart, 
                           criticalDateEnd));
            }
            return null;
        };
```

But it returns an error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Long.

Where is the problem?

By the way, the error is at the long `criticalDateStart` and end line.

Comment: What framework are you using to communicate with the back end?

Comment: Is it possible to avoid casting?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321549/how-to-convert-a-double-to-long-without-casting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `Double`'s method `longValue()`.

```
Long criticalDateStart = ((Double) _arg.get("criticalDateStart")).longValue();
```

Comment: `ScriptObjectMirror` resolve your object as `Double`. While java can convert primitive double to primitive long, its not the case when using corresponding objects. This is simply because `Long` is not a subclass of `Double`.

Comment: aha, ty, I get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `criticalDateStart` and `criticalDateEnd` are doubles, not longs, in your Java code. What you can do:

```
long criticalDateStart = ((Double)_arg.get("criticalDateStart")).longValue();
long criticalDateEnd = ((Double)_arg.get("criticalDateEnd")).longValue();
```